# How to make the "it" in mocha to wait until the promise within "it" gets resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, asynchronous, mocha.js

```
var promise = require('promise');
var {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var chai = require('chai');
var getUrl = require('./wdio.conf.js');
var driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

test.describe('Proper Testing', function() {
    test.it('should prompt the server from user', function() {
        return new promise(function(resolve,reject){
            resolve(driver.get("https://www.google.co.in"));
            reject(err);
        })
    })
})
```

For code given above, running mocha proper.js opens the given url in chrome browser but the test fails with timeout error.
I've read that done() need not be called if test is returning a promise.
What's wrong in the given code?

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to call `done` when your are done testing.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but this example code should make my point:

```
describe('Proper Testing', function() {

    it('should prompt the server from user', function(done) {
        return getUrl().then(function(url){
            driver.get(url)
            .then(function () {
              done();
            }).catch(function (err) {
              done(err);
            });
        })
    });

})
```

Reference: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Nope, done() didn't resolve the issue. Script still results in an error and not waiting for user to respond to prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your problem, try to add a before statement setting a high timeout. Ordinary tests has a default timeout (I think it is 2 seconds), and if the test exceed this time, it raise an error and it doesn't pass the test.

```
before(function (done) {
    this.timeout(5000);
    done();
})
```

Regarding to done: If you are returning a promise, you don't need to use done. Simply declare function() without any parameters, and if it doesn't raise any exception and it accomplish all asserts it finds it pass the test.

```
describe('Proper Testing', function() {

    it('should prompt the server from user', function() {
        return getUrl().then(function(url){
            driver.get(url);
        })
    });

})
```

Comment: I added a timeout of 20 sec to the "it" so that user can respond to prompt and a console.log to verify if the promise does gets resolved. The console statement logs correct url so the promise in getUrl() did get resolved. driver.get(url) also works fine. Now when everything executed why does the script throws the same error?

Comment: Did you set the time in miliseconds (20000)? Did you remove the done parameter?

Comment: Yes I did remove the done parameter and set a timeout in milliseconds. I made edits to the original code given above.

Comment: Just to try, set a return in  driver.get(url);

return driver.get(url);